# 'android:requiered' not found

Tags: android

i am getting the following error message everytime i want to build/clean/rebuild my app.

```
error: attribute 'android:requiered' not found.

Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: attribute 'android:requiered' not found., sources=[C:\Users\M\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

I am highly confused, because my manifest.xml has the code that is requiered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:requiered="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It’s a typo. The correct spelling is `android:required`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the devil itself punished me haha!

Comment: I like when I see this errors at @Stack. They're funny 